# Trying to create a web scraper, but the code below keeps printing all html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So im trying to pull my stats from medium.com and have already built a bot to log in, when i get to the stats page and try to print the title, it keeps throwing all the html at me. The `print` function is there to make sure it's printing the right stuff before I move on:

```
url = driver.page_source
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")

story_title = []
publication = []
views = []
reads = []
read_ratio = []
fans = []

stats_div = soup.find_all('tr', class_='sortableTable-row js-statsTableRow')
for container in stats_div:
    name = container.td.a.text.find('span', class_='sortableTable-title u-maxWidth450')
    story_title.append(name)

print(story_title)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks (get an url would also be cool)

Comment: Suggestion by [Rajasekar C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9744487/rajasekar-c): *Am too new to coding, python and web scraping.
I have been doing webscraping using selenium this week and this is my code:
[webscraping using python and selenium and tried to use multiprocessing but code not working. without it code works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65768906/webscraping-using-python-and-selenium-and-tried-to-use-multiprocessing-but-code)
I could try with your code but it’s not clear what you were intended to do.*

Comment: I cant provide a decent link as this is behind a login page and the other code has my personal info

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, got it! Selenium didn't like `url = driver.page_source` so I just used the link instead.